# Diesel vs petrol NOx / PM?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, engines

I am interested in the comparison of NOx and particulate matte (PM) for modern (Euro 6) diesel engines vs petrol engines? Are the exhaust products produced by both equally carcinogenic?

Comment: why do you have three question marks and only one question?

Answer (score -2):

Gasoline is a fake fuel. Cars are powered by manual effort and gasoline is up to 60% water.

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.swnewsmedia.com/chanhassen_villager/news/local/state-marathon-gasoline-60-percent-water/article_38e46733-b7bb-545f-be36-b9a20221207e.html&ved=2ahUKEwik0vXxpK_-AhXiH0QIHcvDAHoQFnoECBUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0AZzVv8ca8FSMXnED79GwA

So obviously diesel is more emissions.